# How to remove the permission of non-exsist user of a folder of file on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, acl, rsync, explorer

I use rsync of WSL1 to back up my data from disk C:\ to disk D:, the latter one is a USB disk. Recently, I upgrade my C:\ disk to a new one with larger space and install a new Windows in it. In the meanwhile, I copy the backup data from D:\ to new disk. I don't know why there are still a lot of folders and files owned by the users of the Windows installed in the old disk, which means rsync copy the permission of the files and folders simultaneously.

Just like the picture below
[unknow user S-1-5-21-2458767564-679470636-3028966519-1001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mwzg.png)

As a result, neither can I modify the files owned by the old users nor can I read it.
How can I remove the all permissions of the old user for these files and folders as well as its subfolders recursively ?